# How can git bisect pick a commit that doesn't have the first good commit as an ancestor? (using --first-parent)

Tags: git, git-bisect

I have a repository that uses a "trunk" flow with feature branches merging in and creating merge commits, and am using bisect to try find when issues were introduced. The issue identification process involves a comparison to results from a known-good commit, so I am using `git bisect --first-parent` (new in 2.29) to skip commits not in the "trunk" branch (identifying the merge commit that caused the issue is enough for me).

However, `git bisect --first-parent` is picking commits that do not have my first good commit as an ancestor, and I'm unsure how this is possible.

In the below example, commit `2` is good and `4` is bad.

```
  a 
 / \
1-2-3-4
```

Without `--first-parent`, I would expect feature branch commit `a` to be included in the bisection, however with `--first-parent`, I would expect it to skip that commit, and only test the merge commit, `3`.

I've tested this on a mini-repository, and it behaves how I'd expect, however my much larger, much more complicated repository is not skipping commits that don't have `first-good` as an ancestor, and I'm struggling to understand why.

My commands are

```
# both "first-good" and "first-bad" are tags on the "trunk" branch
git bisect start --first-parent
git merge-base --is-ancestor first-good first-bad  # returns TRUE
git merge-base first-good first-bad                # returns first-good
git checkout first-bad 
git bisect bad
git checkout first-good
git bisect good 
git merge-base --is-ancestor first-good HEAD       # returns FALSE - why/how?
git merge-base first-good HEAD                     # returns some other commit - why/how?
```

Comment: The first-parent mode to `git bisect` is new and may have bugs. If you have a reliable reproducer (preferably a short one), send it to the Git mailing list.

Comment: I can work on reproducing in a fake repository, but is the behaviour I observed never expected under all scenarios? Or is there some combination of branch/merge strategy that would invalidate that assumption.

Comment: Given that I have neither worked on nor used the new mode, I can't assure you that this is the case, but logically, `--first-parent` should always just follow the first parent at any merge, and hence never test something that's down a merge leg. I'd like to see the topology of a graph where this misbehaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git@47f0f94bc7, the behaviour described in the question is observed if the `first-good` commit exists in the mainline only as the second parent of merge commit. I guess this is somewhat expected, given the name of the flag, but is does result in confusing behavior if you were relying on the `first-good` commit for a working build, because not all your bisects will contain that commit.

For example:

```
  a - b - c   # "trunk2"
 /   /  
1 - 2         # "trunk1"

# 2 is the `first-good` commit
# c is the `first-bad` commit
```

`git bisect --first-parent` will pick `a` as a commit to test, even though it is not an ancestor of the first known good commit, `2`. It appears to back-track to `a` in this case, which is the first commit that is *not* an ancestor of `first-good`. It does not test `1`, as that is an ancestor of `first-good`, and can thus be assumed to be also good.

In this example, the behaviour with or without the `--first-parents` flag is identical. Other branches starting from and merging back into `trunk2` would continue to be skipped.

While I'm fairly sure this is the "correct" behaviour, and for most use cases, the user won't notice a difference, the man page could use some detailing of this behaviour and/or warning given when the `first-good` commit only exists as a second parent.

This happen in my case because we "re-trunked" at some point, where commits were going into both branches simultaneously.